# Servlet combines data from two different request and replies?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, asynchronous

I have a servlet that gets a ID as parameter and returns three values. Since the servlet code is large ill just give the necessary details.

getdetails.jsp

```
Inputs : ID //as a query string
Returns: ID, average, count // As a JSON string
```

From the client side am making two asynchronous javascript requests one by one (second immediately after 1st request) with different IDs. The responses from the server are as follows:

Responses:

```
For ID1 : ID1, average1, count1
For ID2 : ID1, average2, count2
```

For ID2 it gives correct average and count but returns the ID1 (ID of 1st request).

When I put the same code in getdetails.jsp in getdetails1.jsp and make each request to each servlet, I get correct results.

Responses:

```
For ID1 : ID1, average1, count1
For ID2 : ID2, average2, count2
```

What may be the reason for this and how to correct this?

EDIT:
code of getdetails.jsp:

```
<%!
String ID;
JsonObject details = new JsonObject();  //using Google JSON Lib
%>
<%
ID=request.getParameter("id");
details.addProperty("ID",ID);
...   //accessing corresponding average and count
details.addProperty("average",average);
details.addProperty("count",count);
out.println(details);
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is what @thinksteep suggested. JSP code is translated and compiled into a Servlet. Using the JSP declaration `<%! %>` creates instance variables that aren't thread-safe. You should declare the variables so that they are created new for each request by removing them from the `<%! %>` section and declaring them in the `<% %>` section.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you might have be assigning request parameter values to Servlet instance variables.

Only one instance of servlet will be created and all requests share same instance. Which leads to these type of state corruption.

Comment: NO.. I get the ID each time with request.getParameter("id") method. Also if so there should always be same average and count. But i get average and count corresponding to ID2.

Comment: added a little of implementation to the question.

Comment: I just use the JSP. no servlets.

Answer (score 2):

`The number of servlet instances created by a servlet will always be one.`

If you have assigned the request parameter to servlet instance, this problem might occur.

If this is not the case,

share the little of ID's implementation in servlet, for analysing it.